# Display validation errors when page loads MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a review page that shows the information the users entered in previous pages.  I know that normally MCV displays validations errors when a form is submitted.  I want the validation messages to show when the page is first displayed.  How do I do this?

Comment: That's not how validation works, but you could display whatever message you want by using ViewData or ViewBag

Comment: It'd help if you posted your markup in the view. Are you using the ValidationSummary helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to throw some validation erros in the load of your page you could do something like that

```
public ActionResult MyReadOnlyPage(MyModel model)
{
  /* do your logic with the model */
  ModelState.AddModelError("ModelPropertyName1", "My property error 1");
  ModelState.AddModelError("ModelPropertyName2", "My property error 2");

  return View(model);
}
```

Then if you have ValidationErrorFor or ValidationSummary, your error message should show as expected.
If you instead want an error not linked to a property (so it will show only in the summary) use

```
ModelState.AddModelError("", "generic error");
```

**Update**

The test I did was this (created a new MVC Application form the template):

The model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string surname { get; set; }
}
```

The controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
  var model = new MyViewModel();
  ModelState.AddModelError("name", "errror 1");
  return View(model);
}
```

The html

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.MyViewModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
<p>
  To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
  @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.surname)
</p>
```

and it worked for me. Hope it helps

Comment: I added an error in the calling controller to the ModelState and there is a validation summary on the view but it is not diplaying the error when the page loads

Comment: Tried just to be sure and everithing works. I updated the answer with what I did to have it works